# Johansen Cointegration on a stationary time series?

Tags: r, time-series, cointegration

Following question. Assume we have 6 variables

```
A - stationary at level . I(0)
B - stationary at level . I(0)
C - stationary at level . I(0)
D - stationary at level . I(0)
E - stationary at level . I(0)
F - stationary at level . I(1)
```

We applied a Granger Wald test to

```
A - B with the result that A causes B. Unidirectional.
C - D with the result that C causes D. Unidirectional.
E - F No causality. For this test, we applied a VECM Granger testing model,
      since F was I(1).
```

**Question:**

Is it okay to also test A + B and C + D for Johansen cointegration, though they are both I(0), i.e. stationary at level? We tested E + F for cointegration with each first differences. The point: The results of cointegration were very much the same as for the Granger Wald test.

```
A - B existence of cointegration vector.
C - D existence of cointegration vector.
E - F no existence of cointegration vector.
```

I only wonder why I should maybe not test A + B and C + D with Johansen, or if it's nonsense once both variables are I(0).